# Printing crosstab in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have a DataFrame for car makes and types.

I have used this:

```
conditional_p = pd.crosstab(cars_selected_df.type, cars_selected_df.make, margins=True, normalize='columns')
```

which gives me the conditional probability calculation as I want. However, I am having trouble being able to print the conditional probability % after using pd.crosstab.

If I print conditional_p, it appears like this:

```
make        alfa-romero      audi  bmw  ...  volkswagen     volvo       All
type                              ...                                
standard            1.0  0.714286  1.0  ...    0.833333  0.545455  0.819512
turbo               0.0  0.285714  0.0  ...    0.166667  0.454545  0.180488
```

I want my output to be printed to appear like this:

```
Prob(type=standard | make=alfa-romero) =  100 %
Prob(type=turbo | make=alfa-romero) =  0 %
Prob(type=standard | make=audi) =  71.43 %
Prob(type=turbo | make=audi) =  28.57 %
...
```

for all of the makes (there are 20) and types (2 different types) I have. I was thinking I could use a lamda function to do this, however, how do I refer to the conditional probability value that the crosstab solved for? Do I have to use df.stack() to get the crosstab back into a DataFrame and then I can refer to that within my lambda function? I tried, but still am not getting anywhere.

Here was my attempt at that:

```
y = conditional_p.stack()
cond_probabilities_df =  pd.DataFrame({'car_type':cars_df['type'].unique(), 'make_name':cars_df['make'].unique(), 'cond_prob' : y})
print_cond_probability = lambda x: print('Prob(type='+x.car_type+') | make= '+x.make_name+'= '+x.cond_prob+'%')
```

and I got this error:
ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Side note: I am kinda a novice and not using groupby, only pandas.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I completely misunderstood the question but is something like this, what you're looking for:

```py
for make in conditional_p.columns:
    for typ in conditional_p.index:
        print(f'Prob(type={typ} | make={make}) = {conditional_p[make][typ] * 100:.2f}')
```

Comment: YES! Exactly. I guess I was complicating things with a lambda function?